OSDEV - Exception caused while working with structures
I am currently implementing keyboard's backspace button functionality (I forgot to do that). I have a buffer that remembers user's input.
#define KEYBUFFER_SIZE_DEFAULT  255

u8 _keyb_enable = 0;
u8 _keyb_wait = 0;

u8 _keyb_putc = 0;

size_t _keyb_size = KEYBUFFER_SIZE_DEFAULT;
size_t _keyb_index = 0;

u8 _keyb_color_deleted;

char _ignore;

static unsigned char* _keyb;

There is a function executed by keyboard interrupt handler. It has to append last pressed char to the buffer and remove the last one if backspace is pressed, but it also has to remove that char from the screen and that is where it fails:
void keybuffer_append(char c) {
    if(_ignore == c)
        return;

    if(c == '\b') {
        coords xy = console_wherexy();
        xy.x--;

        console_gotoxy(xy);
        putc(' ');

        _keyb[_keyb_index] = '\0';
        _keyb_index--;
        
        return;
    }

    if(_keyb_enable) {
        _keyb[_keyb_index] = c;
        _keyb_index++;

        if(_keyb_putc)
            putc(c);
    }
}
// ...
inline void console_gotoxy(coords xy) {
    console_position = xy;
}

coords console_wherexy() {
    return console_position;
}
// ...
struct xy2d {
    u8 x;   // Horizontal
    u8 y;   // Vertical
    // ...
};

typedef struct xy2d coords;
typedef struct xy2d dimensions;

Also, here is the code of putc, which works as excepted:
coords console_position;

size_t console_row;
size_t console_column;

u8 console_color;
u16* console_buffer;

// ...

void console_put(char c, u8 color, size_t x, size_t y) {
    const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
    console_buffer[index] = vga_entry(c, color);
}
 
void putc(char c) {
    if(c == '\n') {
        console_position.x = 0;
        console_position.y++;

        return;
    }

    if(c == '\b') {
        if(console_position.x == 0 && console_position.y != 0) {
            console_position.x = VGA_WIDTH;
            console_position.y --;
        }

        if(console_position.x == 0 && console_position.y == 0) {
            return;
        }

        console_position.x--;
    }

    if (++console_position.x == VGA_WIDTH) {
        if(console_position.y != VGA_HEIGHT) {
            console_position.x = 0;
            console_position.y++;
        } else {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < VGA_WIDTH; i++) {
                console_buffer[i] = console_buffer[i + 1];
            }

            console_position.x = 0;
            console_position.y--;
        }
    }

    console_put(c, console_color, console_position.x - 1, console_position.y); 
}

The output on emulator screen is:
----- KERNEL PANIC -----
REGISTERS:
err_code=10
eax=0xa, ebx=0x12572c, ecx=0x78, edx=0x125742
edi=0xa, esi=0x12572c, ebp=0x78, esp=0x125742
eip=0xa, cs=0x12572c, ss=0x78, eflags=0x125742, useresp=0x125746
EXCEPTION: (null)

CPU is now halted. If debugging enabled, check the debug log for more information.
--------------

If needed, the rest of source code can be found at my new GitHub repo.
If backspace pressed, last character pressed before backspace should be cleared, but instead, the output on COM1 says Invalid opcode exception, apparently caused with console positioning functions console_gotoxy or console_wherexy.

Given only this code it appears console_buffer will always be NULL.
